# How to specify different nohup.out files for multiple JVMs running into the same script?

Tags: shell, jvm, nohup

I have a shell script launching different Java JVMs in parallel and sequential, it looks like this:

```
(java -jar project1.jar
java -jar project2.jar) &
(sleep 60;
java -jar project3.jar
java -jar project4.jar) &
(sleep 120;
java -jar project5.jar) &
(sleep 180;
java -jar project6.jar
java -jar project7.jar)
```

I launch my shell script using the following command :

```
nohup sh launch.sh &
```

It generates a unique `nohup.out` file with the different JVMs outputs scrambled.
I'd like to have **1 nohup file per JVM** (let's say nohupProject1.out, nohupProject2.out...) containing its specific output.

Is it possible ?
Maybe by adding some JVM arguments ?

Thank you

Comment: Why should the JVM have options for something so completely unrelated to it? Just use output redirection via `>`…

Comment: @Holger I thought about something like the GC log file that can be specified by JVM arguments. Anyways, the redirection via `>` is applicable on all the script, so all the output of the script will be redirected, I would like to redirect output of JVM1 to output1, JVM2 to output2...etc. (Considering the fact that all JVMs are belonging to the SAME script).

Comment: You can apply `>` to *every* command inside the script.

Comment: @Holger can you please explain how in details as an answer ?

Comment: `java -jar project1.jar >desiredoutputfile` … 
 

 
`java -jar project2.jar >differentoutputfile` … I really don’t get the point of the question

Comment: And the `&` is put after the file name ? I just asked you to write this as an answer of the question (not a comment) in order to validate it :)